# Showing subplots at each pass of a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would essentially like to do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()

for i in range(10):

    ax1.scatter(i, np.sqrt(i))
    ax1.show() # something equivalent to this

    ax2.scatter(i, i**2)
```

That is, each time a point is plotted on ax1, it is shown - ax2 being shown once.

Comment: Do you have something slowing down you code that you don't show?  Otherwise this will run almost instantly and there won't really be a difference between showing it each loop and showing it once.  With that being said, `fig1.show()` is what you are looking for I think.

Comment: I'm making an in python animation of ax1, hence the need to show at each pass in the loop. Following your suggestion i got the following error:
Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  fig1.show()

Comment: Oh, that may not work if you are doing an animation. Haven't done that with matplotlib before, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show an axes alone. An axes is always part of a figure. For animations you would want to use an interactive backend. Then the code in a jupyter notebook could look like

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()

frames = 10
x = np.arange(frames)
line1, = ax1.plot([],[], ls="", marker="o")
line2, = ax2.plot(x, x**2, ls="", marker="o")
ax2.set_visible(False)



def animate(i):
    line1.set_data(x[:i], np.sqrt(x[:i]))
    ax1.set_title(f"{i}")
    ax1.relim()
    ax1.autoscale_view()
    if i==frames-1:
        ax2.set_visible(True)
        fig2.canvas.draw_idle()

ani = FuncAnimation(fig1, animate, frames=frames, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change plots dynamically I'd suggest you don't redraw the whole plot every time, this will result in very laggy behavior. Instead you could use Blit to do this. I used it in a previous project. Maybe it can help you too if you just take the parts from this you need:

[Python project dynamically updating plot](https://www.pastebin.com/NjAQNdHJ)